# Filter an Array into another page of an excel spreadheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, array

I have an excel table that includes one column that lists Y, N, N/A, or Blank.  I need my filter to pull the rows that include the N, or Blank and paste them into another page of the spreadsheet.

I have seen another example: http://www.exceltactics.com/make-filtered-list-sub-arrays-excel-using-small/

but I cannot get it to array properly.  Can anyone give me a code for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

For Excel 2010 or 2013, I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. From Excel 2016, Power Query is built in to the Data ribbon under "Get and Transform" section.

Power Query can start from an Excel table. You can filter a column to choose the values you want.  A Query result can be written to a new Excel Table.